# How to make button execute on same page but not the next page

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql

Hi all Im a new learner for web development.

I have a page with a form after user click the submit button, then button will submit the form content to the next page to execute and save into database.

So that, my page will go to another page to execute and return to the landing page.

Eg: index.php and exec.php

index.php:

```
<form name="g-form" action="gbtn-exec.php" method="post" class="goat-vote" onsubmit="return validategForm()">
<input type="text" name="g-product" placeholder="Brand / Product Name" style="-moz-border-radius: 5px; border-radius: 5px; padding-left:20px; opacity:.5; border:none; margin-left:110px; width:440px; height:38px; font-family:'Proxima Nova Rg';color:#000; font:1.6em;" />


<p class="g-question">Why you love it?</p>

<textarea name="g-reason" style="-moz-border-radius: 5px; border-radius: 5px; padding:5px; opacity:.5; border:none; margin-left:110px; width:450px; height:150px; font-family:'Proxima Nova Rg';color:#333; font-size:1em;"></textarea>

<input name="g-btn" class="vote-btn" type="submit" value="vote" style="margin-left:470px; cursor:pointer;"></form>
```

exec.php

```
if ($_POST["g-product"] && $_POST["g-reason"] != "" )
{
$gproduct = $_POST["g-product"];
$greason =  $_POST["g-reason"];

$insert ="INSERT INTO jovine.vote (vote_id ,product_name ,reason ,type) VALUES (NULL, '$gproduct', '$greason', 'goat')";
$result = mysql_query($insert,$con);
echo "<script>";
echo "alert('Thank you. Your vote has been recorded.');";
echo "window.location.href='index.php';";
echo "</script>";
}
```

My question is, how can I execute the submit button in the index.php without going to the exec.php? (means to combine both in a .php)
It is because when user click submit button it goes to a blank page to execute which do not look nice.

anyone can help? Thanks!
=)

Comment: Use ajax method to execute exec.php in background and retrieve the result in index.php

Comment: try using jquery ajax

Comment: @DonovanCharpin may I know how should i write the script? Im kinda dont understand the maunal... =(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (isset($_POST["g-btn"]))
{
 $gproduct = $_POST["g-product"];
 $greason =  $_POST["g-reason"];

 $insert ="INSERT INTO jovine.vote (vote_id ,product_name ,reason ,type) VALUES (NULL, '$gproduct', '$greason', 'goat')";
 $result = mysql_query($insert,$con);
 echo "<script>";
 echo "alert('Thank you. Your vote has been recorded.');";
 echo "window.location.href='index.php';";
 echo "</script>";
}

<html>
<form name="g-form" action="a.php" method="post" class="goat-vote" onsubmit="return validategForm()">
<input type="text" name="g-product" placeholder="Brand / Product Name" style="-moz-border-radius: 5px; border-radius: 5px; padding-left:20px; opacity:.5; border:none; margin-left:110px; width:440px; height:38px; font-family:'Proxima Nova Rg';color:#000; font:1.6em;" />


<p class="g-question">Why you love it?</p>

<textarea name="g-reason" style="-moz-border-radius: 5px; border-radius: 5px; padding:5px; opacity:.5; border:none; margin-left:110px; width:450px; height:150px; font-family:'Proxima Nova Rg';color:#333; font-size:1em;"></textarea>

<input name="g-btn" class="vote-btn" type="submit" value="vote" style="margin-left:470px; cursor:pointer;"></form>
</html>
```

you can do like this... isset($_POST["g-btn"]) will check if it's get clicked or not?

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** Ignore this please, didn't read your question completely as it seems

Try something like this:

index.php

```
<form name="g-form" action="gbtn-exec.php" method="post" class="goat-vote" onsubmit="return validategForm()">
    <input type="text" name="g-product" placeholder="Brand / Product Name" style="-moz-border-radius: 5px; border-radius: 5px; padding-left:20px; opacity:.5; border:none; margin-left:110px; width:440px; height:38px; font-family:'Proxima Nova Rg';color:#000; font:1.6em;" />

    <p class="g-question">Why you love it?</p>

    <textarea name="g-reason" style="-moz-border-radius: 5px; border-radius: 5px; padding:5px; opacity:.5; border:none; margin-left:110px; width:450px; height:150px; font-family:'Proxima Nova Rg';color:#333; font-size:1em;"></textarea>

    <?php if(!isset($_GET['hidesubmit'])): ?>
    <input name="g-btn" class="vote-btn" type="submit" value="vote" style="margin-left:470px; cursor:pointer;">
    <?php endif; ?>
</form>
```

exec.php

```
if ($_POST["g-product"] && $_POST["g-reason"] != "" )
{
    $gproduct = $_POST["g-product"];
    $greason =  $_POST["g-reason"];

    $insert ="INSERT INTO jovine.vote (vote_id ,product_name ,reason ,type) VALUES (NULL, '$gproduct', '$greason', 'goat')";
    $result = mysql_query($insert,$con);
    echo "<script>";
    echo "alert('Thank you. Your vote has been recorded.');";
    echo "window.location.href='index.php?hidesubmit=1';";
    echo "</script>";
}
```

Comment: It should work, but you wanted a solution which works without sending the form - my solution sends the form and redirects to the original page with a special parameter. On the basis of this parameter the submit button is displayed or not.

Answer (score 0):

Add jQuery lib in your head and your jQuery perso (myjQuery.js) that you will use after for ajax

**index.php**

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/myjQuery.js"></script>
```

Create your form without action on your form.

```
<html>
    <form name="g-form" class="goat-vote">
        <input type="text" name="g-product" placeholder="Brand / Product Name" style="-moz-border-radius: 5px; border-radius: 5px; padding-left:20px; opacity:.5; border:none; margin-left:110px; width:440px; height:38px; font-family:'Proxima Nova Rg';color:#000; font:1.6em;" />
        <p class="g-question">Why you love it?</p>
        <textarea name="g-reason" style="-moz-border-radius: 5px; border-radius: 5px; padding:5px; opacity:.5; border:none; margin-left:110px; width:450px; height:150px; font-family:'Proxima Nova Rg';color:#333; font-size:1em;"></textarea>
        <input name="g-btn" class="vote-btn" value="vote" style="margin-left:470px; cursor:pointer;">
    </form>
</html>
```

Keep your exec.php like this

**exec.php**

```
if ($_POST["g-product"] && $_POST["g-reason"] != "" )
{
    $gproduct = $_POST["g-product"];
    $greason =  $_POST["g-reason"];
    $insert ="INSERT INTO jovine.vote (vote_id ,product_name ,reason ,type) VALUES (NULL, '$gproduct', '$greason', 'goat')";
    $result = mysql_query($insert,$con);
    echo "<script>";
    echo "alert('Thank you. Your vote has been recorded.');";
    echo "window.location.href='index.php?hidesubmit=1';";
    echo "</script>";
}
```

and create myjQuery.js

**myjQuery.js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".vote-btn").on("click", function(){
        g-product = $("input[name='g-product']").val();
        g-reason = $("input[name='g-reason']").val();
        $.ajax({cache:false,dataType:'html',crossDomain:true,type:'POST',
            url:'/php/exec.php',data : {g-product:g-product, g-reason:g-reason},
            success:function(html){
                console.log(html);
            },
            error:function(j,t,e){
                console.log('problem');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

You can try this code, maybe there are problems with js path or php path of your files. And maybe some mistakes that you can correct.